# Google has listed me as https://

Tags: .htaccess, https

Has anyone come across such an issue before? Where there site has been listed at https instead of http:

My homepage has been listed as https:// so when they visit it they get a security warning, i have never had and never mentioned ssl anywhere on my website at any point.

Does anyone have any ideas what this could be and how i can rectify it?

Is there any possible way i can redirect anyone that ever goes to https to http.

I have already tried putting in 301 redirects with no luck.

Thank you!

Comment: Rules can redirect to `http://` but cert warning will still come.

Comment: how will can i redirect for now please? Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```